A mortgage principal reduction before or after refinancing?
I have a high interest rate mortgage that I can refinance at a lower rate. I also want to do a significant lump sum principal reduction.
In which order should I do those two actions to minimize my interest payment (assuming the same interest rate whether I make the lump sum before or after)?

For example:

Scenario A:  $1,000,000 at 7% —> reduce to $800,000 —> refinance at
6%
Scenario B: $1,000,000 at 7% —> refinance at 6% —> reduce to
$800,000.

It seems to me that scenario B would allow me to skip more interests by ”fast forwarding” my amortization schedule ahead in time and get to the part of the monthly payments where more money goes toward the principal. Am I correct?
I am trying to simulate that to put a number on it but I’m not sure about my calculations.

Edit: From additional research I guess we can untangle 4 meaningful parameters that impact the borrower's short and long term payments (given fixed new rates, closing costs):

the total repayment, or total interests cost of the loan
the monthly payments, or affordability
and the amortization schedule, or what I would call the efficiency of those payments (how much go towards the principal vs interests).
the loan duration, or will I live to see the day where my "mort-gage" (see french meaning) is paid off...

And the tools available are:

Refinancing: No extra payment. Brand new loan to reduce the rate effectively reduces the monthly payments + total interests on a new mortgage. But it increases the loan period + resets the amortization schedule to high interests/low principal payments upfront.
Principal reduction: Extra payment(s). Keep the same rate + monthly payments but shortens the duration of the loan + effectively skip ahead in the amortization schedule (which means I save on the interests on the proportional amount? Or is it better than proportional since most of the interest are paid in the beginning years of the loan??)
Recasting: Extra payment. Keep the same rate + duration but reevaluate and lower the monthly payments and amortization schedule.


Should we assume that reducing to $800K and refinancing take the same about of time? Because where I live, mortgage payments get applied within days, but refinancing can take months.

Both can happen within a month time, 2 months max. So I'd say yeah let's ignore interest rates variations and such.

Why can't you do them at the same time? Take out the new mortgage for $800,000 and use that and the $200,000 you have on hand to pay off the old mortgage?

As I commented to a reply below, "at the same time" is either scenario A or B. Do I take a brand new smaller loan or a loan with the same amount and pay off the principal to skip ahead on the amortization schedule?

"At the same time" is different from both A and B. 1) Take out new loan for $800,000 at 6% 2) Use that money and your $200,000 to pay off the $1,000,000 loan at 7%.


In which order should I do those two actions to minimize my interest payment (assuming the same interest rate whether I make the lump sum before or after)?

Option B would minimize the interest paid. But you could also reduce the interest from Option A by refinancing to a shorter term mortgage.
If both refinancing options are the same term (e.g. 30Y), then Option A results in a lower monthly payment but will take longer to pay off. Option B results in a larger monthly payment but a shorter effective term (because you pay it down sooner).
Typically, when you refinance a mortgage you reset the term to a standard term (15, 20, 30 years). So it will depend on how much the 200k reduces the term as to whether it's the same as refinancing to a shorter term and bringing the payment to closing.
Your mortgage broker or bank you're working with should be able to give you the schedule for different scenarios to compare the net result. You might also get a better interest rate if you reduce the principal upfront, depending on your loan-to-value ratio before and after.
In both cases be VERY aware of the closing costs. If you aren't diligent you could end up paying a ton in closing costs which can take years to break-even. Typically you want a break-even time (closing costs / interest saved per month) of about 3 years to make it worth it.

In what world would not paying off the higher interest balance be better than paying it off? I'm not sure I understand your answer.

I'm not sure what you mean by "doing them together". It's either scenario A or B even if it's bundled into a refinancing. I guess what you're saying is B? so i move forward into the amortization schedule?

Thanks for the warning on closing costs. Definitely needs to be added to the comparison to measure the delta

@littleadv I'm saying it depends on whether you want a lower monthly payment or to pay it off sooner. And if you refinance to a shorter term then the difference is smaller.

The OP is asking how to minimize the overall interest. I'm not sure if the principal reduction refers to recasting, it's not clear from the question if that's even an option.

@littleadv yes on minimizing interest rates! Otherwise I do not want recasting as this supposes keeping same rate and a new amortization schedule and Principal reduction allows to skip ahead in the schedule.

@DStanley thanks on the clarification. Option B it is then, if on top of reducing the monthly payments it allows to pay less interests.


To first order both options are equivalent: you are paying off $800,000 at a rate of 6%
Option A results in a lower monthly payment, but a longer pay-off period (and hence more total interest).
Option B has a higher monthly payment and accordingly a shorter pay-off period (and hence lower total interest).
There may be significant differences in fees, charges, points, closing costs etc.

Provided the fees are the same and there are no pre-payment penalties, go with option A. You can just pay more to pay it off earlier whenever you feel like it. In other words: you can adjust A to behave exactly like B but not the other way around. A gives you more flexibility.

I think ignoring time is a mistake.  Provided you have the money, you can make the 200K payment today.  Even if you can close on the refinance within 30 days, and I find that somewhat unlikely, you will save  1% on 200k for about a month.
Its not life changing money so this may be more theoretical than anything else.
